# If $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ and $(y_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ are convergent in $\mathbb{R}^m$ , then $\|x_n - y_n\|$ is convergent in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

To demonstrate this proposition I use the following:

**Definition** $\quad$ $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\subset \mathbb{R}^m$ converges to $x\in\mathbb{R}^m$ if and only if $\forall \varepsilon >0 $ there is $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\|x_n - x\|<\varepsilon$.

Assuming that $(y_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges to $y$ in $\mathbb{R}^m$, my main idea to probe is:

$\| x_n-y_n\| = \| x_n - x +y - y_n +x -y \|$
$\quad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \leq \| x_n - x \|+\|y - y_n\| +\|x -y \| < \varepsilon +\varepsilon + \|x -y \|$.

And there I stay, because do not know how to relate $\|x -y\|$ with $\varepsilon$.

Comment: Start from $||(x_n-y_n)-(x-y)||$ and everything will fall in place. Your scheme of proof is used when you have some reason to believe that the difference tends to zero, but it does not necessarily.

Comment: What does $\|x-y\|$ mean in your post? This notation is often used for a norm in at [normed space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normed_vector_space). However, since you have $x\in\mathbb R$ and you add real number $\varepsilon$ to $\|x-y\|$, it seems more probable that in your case it is somewhat unusual notation for absolute value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $x_n\to A$ and $y_n\to B$. Then for any $\varepsilon>0$ there is some $N_\varepsilon$ such that, for any $n\geq N_\varepsilon$, *both* $\|x_n-A\|$ and $\|y_n-B\|$ are less that $\varepsilon$. It follows that, for any $n>N_\varepsilon$:

$$ \|x_n-y_n\| = \|(x_n-A)-(y_n-B)+(A-B)\| = \|A-B\|+E $$
with $0\leq \|E\|\leq 2\varepsilon$ and $\|x_n-y_n\|\to \|A-B\|$.

Comment: I forgot to mention that $(x_n) \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and $(y_n) \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ just as $x,\, y \in\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: How do I justify that $\| x_n-y_n \| \to \| A-B \|$? Or rather: How do I justify that $\|x_n-y_n \| \to \| x-y \|$?

Comment: @mathsalomon: it is just a consequence of the triangle inequality, and a rather trivial consequence, too. If $x_n$ is "aribitrarily close" to $A$ and $y_n$ is "aribitrarily close" to $B$ it is rather natural to expect that $x_n-y_n$ cannot be too far from $A-B$.

Comment: $$ \|(x_n-y_n)-(A-B)\|\leq \|x_n-A\|+\|y_n-B\|.$$

Comment: I already understood you. Thank you very much Jack, help me fully.